# With curl, how to authenticate to databricks api?

Tags: curl

SOF,

I want to use the rest api to access my databricks cluster.

I read this document:

https://forums.databricks.com/storage/temp/32-dbcthirdpartyintegrationrestapi11.pdf

I think the authentication portion of the document is poorly written.

It gives a general idea but has no examples.

Even if it did have examples, the pdf-text does not copy well into my mouse.
They should place this kind of information in a web-page or source file I can clone from github.

Anyway,
I started with a simple curl command in bash:

`curl https://abc-xyz123-0411.cloud.databricks.com/api/1.2/clusters/list`

I got this response:

Error 401 Unauthorized

I went to google: how to authenticate to databricks api?

I found nothing useful via google.

Question: With curl, how to authenticate to databricks api?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using python instead of curl:

```
# rest1.py

# This script should demo databricks REST API.

# ref:
# goog: With python how to authenticate to REST API?
# http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

import requests

usr='dog@catnip.net'
pas='abc123'

hhost         = 'https://abc-12345-911.cloud.databricks.com/api/1.2'
clusters_list = hhost+'/clusters/list'

rq1 = requests.get(clusters_list, auth=(usr,pas))
print(rq1.status_code)
print(rq1.json())
'done'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are updated [instructions in the Databricks docs](http://docs.databricks.com/api/1.2/index.html#example-upload-spark-jar-and-run-in-databricks) notebooks which include `curl` examples. For example:

> List the Spark Clusters in Databricks:
>
> ```
> % curl -u username:password https://YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME.cloud.databricks.com/api/1.2/clusters/list
>
> [
>   {
>       "driverIp": "10.0.236.4",
>       "id": "batVenom",
>       "jdbcPort": 10000,
>       "name": "Mini-Cluster",
>       "numWorkers": 2,
>       "status": "Running"
>   }
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we are using curl to start databricks cluster

```
curl -X POST --header 'content-type:application/json' --header 'authorization:Bearer $databricks-token' -d '{"cluster_id": $cluster_id}' https://YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/clusters/start --insecure -v
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
curl --request GET "https://YOUR_HOST_URL/api/2.1/jobs/runs/list" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN" \
     --data '{ "cluster_id": "OPTIONAL_CLUSTER_ID" }'
```